# Master thesis in Finance in search of topic concerning investor sentiment and financial crash

Tags: volatility

Is there any good idea that combines low volatility, risk aversion level of investors and prediction of financial crash ?
Is there any literature?

Comment: Your question does not seem clear to me. What exactly are you interested in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most applicable framework is Hyman Minsky's Financial Instability Hypothesis available as a paper at levyinstitute.org .  That author also has at least two excellent books on the subject. Briefly, stability is destabilizing because it encourages leverage that makes the system increasingly fragile.